# I can't edit Text Field in Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I developed a React App using Material-UI then I tried to create **independent Components**,

check the below independent components(`<PanelDiv/>`),

```
render() {
        return (
            <div className="panelDiv-component" style={{display:this.props.display}}>
                <div className="panel-field-content">
                    <TextField
                        floatingLabelText={this.props.heading}
                        type={this.props.inputType}
                        value={this.props.value}
                    />
                   {/* <input  defaultValue className="form-control"></input>*/}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

I tried to use the component like this,

```
<PanelDiv
    heading='name'
    inputType="text"
    value={this.state.userData.name}
    display={this.state.display[0]}
/>
```

But I can't update input field in this way.Also there is no error. How can i solve this? I want to update my input field.

Please check my input filed in the below image :

[image]

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because you are controlling the value of `TextField` by using `value` attribute but you are not updating the value by using `onChange` function, Since value of `TextField` is not changing so it becomes read only.

**Solution:**

Specify the `onChange` function with `TextField` and update the value inside that, Like this:

```
<TextField
    floatingLabelText={this.props.heading}
    type={this.props.inputType}
    value={this.props.value}
    onChange={this.props._change}
/>
```

Inside parent component:

```
_Change(event, value){
   //update the value here
}


<PanelDiv
    heading='name'
    inputType="text"
    value={this.state.userData.name}
    _change={this._change}
    display={this.state.display[0]}
/>
```

Comment: @ThilinaSampath you also need to pass the onChnage function via props, check the updated answer :)

Comment: no. how i get TextField name in **_Change** method inside, I am try for this

Comment: assign the name to text field, like `name='abc'` or any other value and use `event.target.name` to get the name inside `_change` function :)

Comment: this is event **Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: ReactDOMComponent, nativeEvent: InputEvent, type: "change", target: input#undefined-undefined-name-22459, …}** there are not find .name

Comment: have you tried `console.log(event.target.name)` what it is printing?

Answer (score 18):

If you pass value as a prop to TextField you can't change that text!
On [Material-UI official documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#form-props) they have used defaultValue="default val" as a prop.
So I used defaultValue as a prop! It worked fine for me!

```
<TextField 
   type="text"
   defaultValue={this.props.val}
   onChange={handleChange} 
  />
```

Comment: +1 Can confirm this is the right way to be using the non-controlled textfield value for MUI.
Good reference to official documentation too :)

Comment: This saved my life. Same goes with a MUI's Input field.

Answer (score 7):

Had the same error. I was not able to key in anything and it was because there was no name props included. example:

```
<TextField
  type="email"
  name='email'/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at this example - https://jsfiddle.net/y857yeLq/

You should define a function, which is handles of text change and pass it to `onChange` property. In this example I used state for storing current text field value. I see, that you use props for that, but the principle is the same - function should update props in your case.

```
const { TextField, MuiThemeProvider, getMuiTheme } = MaterialUI;

 class SliderExampleControlled extends React.Component {

  state = {
    value: '',
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div style={{width: '50%', margin: '0 auto'}}>
        <TextField
          hintText="Type here"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={(e) => this.setState(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

const App = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <SliderExampleControlled />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Try to change `Profile.js` file like this - https://jsfiddle.net/hg4Lom8w/1/ and `DivField.js` file like this - https://jsfiddle.net/1qyfnv3r/ Is it working? If not, what messages in console do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this problem as well and I needed the onClick function to take more than just the event I also needed it to take the row number because my state had an array representing the rows in a table. I was able to do that using this chunk of code

```
onChange={(e) => this.nameChange(e.target.value, row.row_num)}
```

then in my function called nameChange I was able to update the value